# Physical meaning of the power spectrum: information it gives about the frequency content of a noise

Tags: statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

Consider a stationary random variable $F(t)$ representing the random force on a Brownian particle in a fluid. Suppose the autocorrelation function is given by $$\langle F(0)F(t)\rangle=Ce^{-\gamma|t|}$$ where $C$ is a constant of appropriate dimension and $\gamma$ is a real positive constant. Then the Power spectrum $S_F(\omega)$, defined as $$S_F(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt~ e^{i\omega t}\langle F(0)F(t)\rangle$$ turns out as $$S_F(\omega)=\frac{C}{\gamma^2+\omega^2}$$ which decreases as $\omega$ increases.

On the other hand, the power spectral density of a delta correlated noise $\xi(t)$ i.e., $\langle\xi(0)\xi(t)\rangle=K\delta(t)$ turns out to be independent of frequency $\omega$.

*What physical information does the power spectrum $S_F(\omega)$ provide about the nature of the random variable $F(t)$ in this case? In particular, what does $S_F(\omega)$ tell about the "frequency content" of the random variable $F(t)$? Since it is a Lorentzian (the spectral density drops as $\omega$ drops) large frequency components of the noise contributes lesser than small frequency components?*

*And what about constant power spectrum of the delta-correlated noise $\xi(t)$? Does it mean all frequency components contribute equally to make up $\xi$?*

Comment: Statistical, not physical: it is just an [Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein–Uhlenbeck_process).

Comment: The power spectrum being a [Lorentzian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), i.e. a Cauchy (Breit-Wigner!) distribution, it means it has no frequency moments; that is, the FT autocorrelation function is highly peaked. It models the velocity of a massive Brownian particle under the influence of friction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** I'm using $$S_F(\omega) \equiv \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt e^{i \omega t} \left \langle F(0)F(t) \right \rangle$$
because I believe it is considerably more standard than the definition given in the question post.

---

> What physical information does the power spectrum $S_F(\omega)$ provide about the nature of the random variable $F(t)$ in this case?

The power spectral density tells you exactly what it sounds like: the amount of fluctuations at a given frequency.
There are a few ways to see the meaning of "amount of fluctuations at a given frequency", the most direct and possibly intuitive is to directly relate how much the particle moves around to its power spectral density.

### Mean square motion of particle

Let us ask a concrete physical question: given that the particle starts at $x=0$, what is it the probability distribution of its position after a time $t$?
Since the motion of the particle is presumably due to a sum of a large number of small fluctuations, the central limit theorem guarantees that the probability distribution is Gaussian.
Therefore, it's enough for us to compute the variance.
We can always write $x(t)$ as an integral of its velocity, i.e.
$$x(t) = \int_0^t \dot{x}(t') \, dt' \,.$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\left \langle x(t)^2 \right \rangle
&= \int_0^t dt' \int_0^t dt'' \left \langle \dot{x}(t') \dot{x}(t'') \right \rangle \\
&= \int_0^t dt' \int_0^t dt'' \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} S_{\dot{x}}(\omega) e^{-i \omega (t' - t'')} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} S_{\dot{x}}(\omega) \int_0^t dt' \int_0^t dt'' e^{-i \omega (t' - t'')} \\
&= 2 t^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} S_{\dot{x}} (\omega) \underbrace{\left( \frac{1 - \cos(\omega t)}{(\omega t)^2} \right)}_{W(\omega,t)} \, . \tag{$\star$}
\end{align}
This result can be interpreted as a weighting function $W(\omega, t)$ integrated against the spectral density.

[image]
**Figure 1:** $W(\omega, t)$ for the free particle case.

The exact form of this weighting function is particular to the case where we let the particle drift freely.
If we were to filter the particle's motion (e.g. if this were an electrical signal instead of a physical particle) or change the boundary conditions in some way, we'd have a different form for $W$.

In the case of strong damping, which I believe is the case for Brownian motion, we have a large drag force $F_\text{drag} = - \gamma \dot{x}$ and Newton's law goes like this
\begin{align}
F_\text{total} &= m\ddot{x} \\
F_\text{external} - \gamma \dot{x} &= m\ddot{x} \leftarrow \text{(small compared to other side)} \\
F_\text{external}/\gamma &= \dot{x} \, .
\end{align}
Therefore, force and velocity are proportional to each other.

The $W$ we got in this case is large for small $\omega$.
This means that the diffusion of the free particle is dominated by force fluctuations at low frequency.
This isn't surprising: if the spectral density is large at low frequency then the force has a large roughly constant component, which pushes the particle in one direction.
Spectral density at higher frequencies corresponds to force fluctuations that oscillate in time, and contribute less to the particle's total movement in a single direction.

### Power spectral density as "power per bandwidth"

This section is a work in progress.
I've saved it in an incomplete state so that I can work on it from another computer.

At the beginning of this post, we said that the power spectral density tells you the amount of fluctuation at a given frequency.
In fact, the power spectral density tells us the *power per frequency bandwidth*.
Let's see what that means quantitatively.

First, rewrite $(\star)$ with the variable change $z \equiv \omega t$:
$$\langle x(t)^2 \rangle
=2 t \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dz}{2 \pi} S_{\dot{x}}(z/t)
\underbrace{\left( \frac{1 - \cos(z)}{z^2} \right)}_{W(z)} \, .$$
If $S_\dot{x}(z/t)$ is a constant $S_\dot{x}$ over the range where $W(z)$ has substantial weight, then we can factor $S$ out of the integral, do the integral, and arrive at
\begin{align}
\langle x(t)^2 \rangle &= t S_\dot{x} \\
\text{or} \quad \langle x(t)^2 \rangle / t &= S_\dot{x} \, .
\end{align}
Thinking of $\langle x(t)^2 \rangle$ as "energy", the left hand side is energy per time or power.
Therefore, $S_\dot{x}$ is the

Comment: It would be helpful for me if you could address the specific example I mentioned. What does the power spectrum of the random force tell us? In terms of the force, it may be better to understand first. @DanielSank

Comment: @SRS I did the calculation in terms of $\dot{x}$ because I *think* that in Brownian motion the particle's velocity is proportional to the applied force via a drag coefficient. That being the case, the calculation I showed and the physical interpretation carry over directly to what you asked. Does that answer it?

Comment: @DanielSank - When to use the factor of $2 \pi$ is kind of a matter of choice, is it not?

Comment: @SRS I'm still hoping to answer your question. Let me know what else I can add.

Comment: Give me some time to appreciate your answer. @DanielSank

Comment: @honeste_vivere yes, but so is choice of language to speak, and it's best to speak the same ones that others speak. There are several ways to choose Fourier transform pairs, but none of the common ones put the $1/2\pi$ with the integration over time.

Comment: @DanielSank - This is really a side note (i.e., not a criticism nor does this imply I think you should change anything in your answer) but "common" is subjective here to the books you have read.  I have seen several books that put the $2\pi$ factor in the forward transform and several that split it between forward and reverse (i.e., $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ for each).  The same is true for FFTs in different programming languages.  It's really a matter of choice and the key thing is to remember which choice you made to avoid stray factors of $2\pi$.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Please provide a link to or name of a single resource where the $2\pi$ shows up in the time integration. I know there are cases with $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ in both integrations, but I've never seen $2\pi$ in the time integration, ever.

Comment: @DanielSank - I will try to dig around for this next week when I get back from a meeting I'm attending.  At the moment I just know I have seen both forms on several occasions, but now that you challenge me I am inclined to think I will look and find that the only instances were in math books showing that the two are equivalent forms and it's really a matter of choice...

Comment: Hello, @SRS. Where does this post stand now?

Comment: @DanielSank What does $S_F(\omega)$ tell about the "frequency content" of the random variable $F(t)$? Since it is a Lorentzian (the spectral density drops as $\omega$ drops) large frequency components of the noise contributes lesser than small frequency components? And what about constant power spectrum? Does it mean all frequency components contribute equally?

Comment: @DanielSank Without introducing Weighting function $W(\omega,t)$ can we not understand the concept of the spectral density?

Comment: @SRS yes the power spectral density $S(\omega)$ is just the power *per bandwidth* that would remain in the signal if it were filtered to a band centered at $\omega$. In other words, if the filter width is $\Delta \omega$, then the power is $P=S(\omega) \Delta \omega$. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I gave the answer in terms of the time domain behavior because I thought that's what the OP was asking. I can add more information though.